# Building Workspace has encountered an error in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-developer-api

I'm using eclipse android version. It is Neon.3 and whenever I create a new android project, I get this error:

> Building Workspace has encountered a problem

[image: this is the screenshot of that error]

I searched everywhere on the internet but could not find a fix to this problem

Comment: Just a general question, what is the use/value of still using eclipse?

Comment: sorry i didn't understand

Comment: Why are you still using eclipse and not android studio?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't Google-Android end support Eclipse??

https://www.xda-developers.com/google-set-to-end-support-for-adt-in-eclipse/

Comment: ya  bro i switched to android studio

Comment: yes the problem was solved and now i realized that android studio is much better than eclipse, thank you!

Comment: If this Answer was helpful, please up vote and check for me :)